# how to attach a pdf in mail in x-cart

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, x-cart

Currently, i am working on one project related to x-cart. and what i found is there is no any functionality regarding add attachment to the email. I want to attach one pdf with mail. and I didn't found any solution regarding this. is there any facilities regarding this in x-cart. or is it already in but I am not aware of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untill i know x-cart allows two types of mail sending. you can send simple mail using php mailer with attachment. don't use xcart's personal mail system. i have faced it too. and made solution with php mailer. xcart have no any free modules to send mail with attachments.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to email PDF invoices to buyers.

I googled this:
https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:X-PDF_Invoices
https://market.x-cart.com/addons/PDF-Invoice.html

Comment: I already saw this add-on. but the version we have is 4.7 and there is no any add-on available for it.

Comment: @AshishPatel the 1st link is about X-PDF invoices module for X-Cart 4 . You need to buy it.

Comment: I found an alternative to it. had made another function to execute mail. by the way thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few PDF libraries out there that output to email format. I just used one in a project not so long ago. I used [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/). If you can get a library to output a header and content array in email format, then you can add it straight to X-Cart's content array. Otherwise create an `$output['header']` and `$output['content']` and use that. Remember, it needs to be in the correct email content format. You can't just give it a filename in the above arrays.

Generating the output is fairly straight forward for this library.

```
$output = $PDF->Output('filename.pdf', 'EX');
```

In `func.mail.php`  before...

```
list($message_header, $mail_message) = func_parse_mail($msgs);
```

you would want to add your output there.

```
// Add the attachment
$msgs['content'][] = $output;
list($message_header, $mail_message) = func_parse_mail($msgs);
```

Comment: will it convert the pdf to html and send the mail as a content?

Comment: No, this is how you attach a PDF to your email, as you asked.